# Silently downloading a .txt file to a macbook's desktop

Tags: macos, security, download, silent

Basically I need to download a .txt file to my teachers macbook saying something along the lines of "I was here" including my name & student ID.
If I can manage to do this I instantly pass the security class.
For those of you who want to hear (or read) the story, read the following paragraph, for the rest just skip it.

My teacher from my Computer Security class has given everyone a challenge, the one who leaves a txt file saying you were here on his macbook's desktop will instantly pass the class. He usually keeps an eye on his macbook and if you want access to it you'd have to steal it without him seeing you do it. His disk is encrypted and he has long passwords. I have thought about a few approaches and I want to get as much information on each approach as possible. First approach was simply hanging a recorder somewhere in the room to record him typing in his password then stealing his mac and creating the txt file. Second approach was somehow getting him to run a file that would create said txt file. And third approach is basically injecting javascript code into his sites which silently download the txt file to his desktop. Now I just need to know if it's even possible to silently download said file.

So here we finally come to the question, is there a way of silently downloading a txt file, and if so how would one do it?
And if it isn't possible, does anyone have any ideas for me to place the txt file on his pc?

EDIT: For those of you wondering, its uni/college not some kind of preschool.

Answer (score 0):

Well, Have you performed any scans on this particular macbook? Do they host any services, like a web server or other service from this machine? That would be the traditional starting point.

Otherwise, Social Engineering, is probably the best way forward. You could pull off the student version of what happened to Ross Ulbricht. Wait for them to log into the machine. Then get some of your mates to create a significant distraction. Download and execute a quick executable that places your "proof" on the desktop (Or just be a quick typist) Profit.

Alternately:

1. Create a malicious executable.
2. Change the icon of executable to look like a word document.
3. Name Executable "Love Letter" or something juicy.
4. Place the executable on Flash Drive.
5. Place 5-10 "Boring" useless, normal files on there too. 2-3 pictures. (Just to get his guard down)
6. Leave this flash drive on or (Preferably near) his desk.
7. Wait.

This executable should create the text file on the desktop, pop up a smug message, Take a screenshot, and email both you and him the picture as proof.

The executable should also be designed to no longer work after a certain amount of time.

Comment: Unfortunately I haven't been able to scan the laptop, as the wifi at school is segmented and when you try to touch the macbook he's like NO
I will try out the distraction one though, thanks for that! (Although he usually has the macbook in his hand when he uses it)

Comment: Yeah give it a shot. Don't get in trouble; or your friends. Any other method is going to delve into the realm of possibly being illegal due to the fact that you would have to access systems that you are not authorized to access. i.e the Schools wifi.

Comment: Don't worry about me getting in trouble, you are allowed to actually take his mac to your house if it's not too long lol (if you can that is)

Comment: Some other approaches that are less intrusive: 1.) Make a malicious executable to create the file (as you mentioned). Change the icon to the default word document. A lot of people fall for this. 2.) Place your malicious executable on a cheap thumb drive just like mentioned in #1. Name the executable "Love Letter" or something interesting. Put a bunch of other boring files on there too. Hope tries to open "love letter" which is disguised as a word document. Leave this thumb drive on his desk. Bonus points if you can have it email you when it is executed. for extra proof.

Comment: Thats actually quite a funny idea xD
I'm getting a rubber ducky soon so the "fast typing" won't be a problem :P I'll most likely only need ~5 seconds of him not paying attention (with the pc open that is)
I'll do the love letter thing too! :D

Comment: Good luck. I'd like to know if you succeed. Also, if you do have it email you...put some fail safes in there too. If I was the professor..I'd Execute it 100,000 times just to fill up your inbox.